# ASP.NET membership salt?

Tags: asp.net, security, hash, asp.net-membership

How does ASP.NET membership generate their salt key and then how do they encode it (that is, is it salt + password or password + salt)?

I am using [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) with my membership, but I would like to recreate the same salts so the built-in membership stuff could hash the stuff the same way as my stuff can.

**Edit 2:** Never mind. I misread it and was thinking it said bytes, not bits. So I was passing in 128 bytes, not 128 bits.

**Edit:** I been trying to make it so. This is what I have,

```cs
public string EncodePassword(string password, string salt)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
    byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
    byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);

    HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");

    byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}

private byte[] createSalt(byte[] saltSize)
{
    byte[] saltBytes = saltSize;

    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);

    return saltBytes;
}
```

So I have not tried to see if the ASP.NET membership will recognize this yet the hashed password looks close. I just don't know how to convert it to base64 for the salt.

I did this

```cs
byte[] storeSalt = createSalt(new byte[128]);
string salt = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(storeSalt);
string base64Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(storeSalt);

int test = base64Salt.Length;
```

Test length is 172 which is well over the 128 bits so what am I doing wrong?

This is what their salt looks like

```text
vkNj4EvbEPbk1HHW+K8y/A==
```

This is what my salt looks like

```
E9oEtqo0livLke9+csUkf2AOLzFsOvhkB/NocSQm33aySyNOphplx9yH2bgsHoEeR/aw/pMe4SkeDvNVfnemoB4PDNRUB9drFhzXOW5jypF9NQmBZaJDvJ+uK3mPXsWkEcxANn9mdRzYCEYCaVhgAZ5oQRnnT721mbFKpfc4kpI=
```

Comment: You can check my answer on this SO page:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530426/reimplement-asp-net-membership-and-user-password-hashing-in-ruby/8184569#8184569

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*[What is default hash algorithm that ASP.NET membership uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137368)* has a good discussion of their default algorithm.

I hope that helps!

Edit- 
The answer I was referring to is the code in the top post,

```
   public string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
        //byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt); Corrected 5/15/2013
        byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt); 
        byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
        HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
        byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
    }
```

They are combining Unicode Salt + Pass using BlockCopy

-- In response to your question:

Both algorithms are necessary and fulfill different roles...

RNG Crypto is used to generate the salt. It is basically a long string of random data. This is generated and stored on a per user basis. Typically this is done when a user is created or a password is changed.

BlockCopy is just the method they use to combine the salt with the password. The above code essentially equates to salt + password.

You aren't going to be able to recreate a salt value as it is completely random. It is, however, stored for each user by the framework.

Combining the salt with the password and hashing it using the technique above will allow you to verify users passwords using the hashed value stored by the framework.

I think we both read your question differently. The code I posted won't generate your salt, but it will let you use it in a way that is compatible with ASP.NET membership.

Sorry my explanation isn't the best- does that answer your question?

Comment: Does not tell you how Microsoft does the Salt.

Comment: The top post shows the algorithm - I've copied it here for clarity.

Comment: Sorry- I see what you mean. I assumed that he was looking  for how it was combined to recreate from existing data.

Comment: Hi 

I don't get it. What is blockCopy in the documentation they say they use RNGCrypto. It also does not generate the salt.

Comment: Grr - Having trouble explaining clearly in the comments. I'll add everything to the body of my post. Sorry.

Comment: It is getting their like see my edit. I need to figure out how to generate the salt then I can truly test if .net membership stuff can figure out what is going on. except I can't get 128bit length for the salt.

Comment: Hmm - I just realized that I made a mistake - the variable src should be set by converting from base 64, not getting the string bytes. The correct code is byte[] src =   Convert.FromBase64String(salt);

Comment: Thank you so much for this, Kelly. Exactly what I needed in my situation.

Answer (score 21):

Here is how the SQLMembershipProvider generates salt.

```
    private string GenerateSalt() {
        var buf = new byte[16];
        (new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()).GetBytes(buf);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
   }
```

You can download the ASP.NET's SQL Provider code [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/3/ab3c284b-dc9a-473d-b7e3-33bacfcc8e98/ProviderToolkitSamples.msi).

The issue I was having was a development application running on IIS7. .NET 4.0 was using a different default hash algorithm than the default HashAlgorithmType for .NET 2.0.

In the "EncodePassword" sample code by Microsoft, they reference `Membership.HashAlgorithmType` which I believe returns the default for the framework, if it is not specified in the `web.config`.

I was able to get both this GenerateSalt and EncodePassword method to work for my application.

My combined code:

```
internal string GenerateSalt()
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[16];
    (new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()).GetBytes(buf);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
}

internal string EncodePassword(string pass, int passwordFormat, string salt)
{
    if (passwordFormat == 0) // MembershipPasswordFormat.Clear
        return pass;

    byte[] bIn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] bSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
    byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
    byte[] bRet = null;

    Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);
    if (passwordFormat == 1)
    { // MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed
        HashAlgorithm s = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
        // Hardcoded "SHA1" instead of Membership.HashAlgorithmType
        bRet = s.ComputeHash(bAll);
    }
    else
    {
        bRet = EncryptPassword(bAll);
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bRet);
}
```

Comment: RhinoDevX64, your answer was exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you very much, you ended my days-long struggle trying to figure out how to compare my strings with hash/salt information in the database!

Comment: Thanks for this. But I don't understand how, if the salt is randomly generated, you can then compare the plain text password used at time of login to the stored hashed password. The salt would need to be stored somewhere for it to match right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it. A salt is just a random number, you can use RNGCryptoServiceProvider class in the framework library to produce good random number to use as salt

```
private const int ITERATIONS = 10000;
private const int SALT_SIZE = 32;
private const int HASH_SIZE = 32;

public void SaltAndHashPassword(string password, out byte[] salt,
  out byte[] hash)
{
  Rfc2898DeriveBytes rdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(
    password,
    SALT_SIZE,
    ITERATIONS);

  salt = rdb.Salt;
  hash = rdb.GetBytes(HASH_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Hi I found on msdn this

"PasswordSalt: Randomly generated 128-bit value used to salt password hashes; stored in base-64-encoded form"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx

So what would I do up the salt_size to 128? how about hash size?

Comment: they also have this

MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed (the default), which stores salted hashes generated from passwords and password answers. The salt is a random 128-bit value generated by the .NET Framework's RNGCryptoServiceProvider class. Each password/password answer pair is salted with this unique value, and the salt is stored in the aspnet_Membership table's PasswordSalt field. The result of hashing the password and the salt is stored in the Password field. Similarly, the result of hashing the password answer and the salt is stored in the PasswordAnswer field.