# What does 'someString.each_char { |c| bytes += c + "\x00" }' do?

Tags: ruby

I am implementing a ruby hashing function in javascript. I have encountered a line of code that I'm uncertain what exactly it is doing. Admittedly, it is due to mu lack of ruby experience, but I thought I could draw on your knowledge to help. The bit of code is:

```
someString.each_char { |c| bytes += c + "\x00" }
```

My question is what is this doing? To me it seems it is encoding a string. I would like to say it is UTF8. But I am uncertain. BTW, the string is an command line argument being passed into the program. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It’s adding a NUL character after each character. Maybe trying to convert ASCII to little-endian UTF-16. Where does the hashing function come from?

Comment: It appears that `bytes` is initialized before this expression is executed. No?

Comment: I got this part of the code from this answer. We are doing something similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530426/reimplement-asp-net-membership-and-user-password-hashing-in-ruby

Comment: Cary, thats right. it is initialized like this `bytes = ""`

Comment: Ah, the Ruby code isn’t correct, then; you should be basing your implementation off the .NET one. `Encoding.Unicode` is little-endian UTF-16. Is this client-side JavaScript or Node.js?

Comment: Javascript. (React)